# Data not passing through between Spring server and Angular client

Tags: angular, spring, http-headers

I'm trying to transfer an object from class type "Conductor" which has the details of a bus driver, between the client side Angular through Spring's server side, by using a POST method. When I pass the data, console logs on client side indicate that the object is correctly defined with values, but when I try to print the values on server, it is listed as null. Don't know what I'm missing and I would appreciate all the help I can get.

conductor-view.component.ts on client side

```
export class ConductorViewComponent implements OnInit {

  conductor: Conductor = new Conductor(0, "", "", "", "", "", []);
  
  constructor(
    private conductorService: ConductorService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.conductorService.findConductor(1).subscribe(conductor => this.conductor = conductor);
    
  }

  goNext(): void {
    let nextId = this.conductor.id + 1;
    this.router.navigate(['/conductor/view', nextId]);
  }

  goBack(): void {
    let previousId = this.conductor.id - 1;
    this.router.navigate(['/conductor/view', previousId]);
  }

  saveConductor(){
    this.conductorService.saveConductor(this.conductor).subscribe();
  }

}
```

conductor.services.ts on client side

```
export class ConductorService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private listaConductores: Record<number, Conductor> = {
  };
  getAllConductores(): Observable<Conductor[]> {
    return this.http.get<Conductor[]>("http://localhost:8080/conductores/list");
  }

  findConductor(id: number): Observable<Conductor> {
    return this.http.get<Conductor>("http://localhost:8080/conductores/" + id);
  }

  saveConductor(conductor: Conductor) {
    console.log("Sending: " + JSON.stringify(conductor));
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/conductores", conductor, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      })
    });
  }

}
```

And ConductorController.java on the server side

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/conductores")
public class ConductorController {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    ConductorRepository conductorRepository;

    @Operation(summary = "Find conductor by id")
    @ApiResponses({ @ApiResponse(responseCode="200", description="Found the conductor", content = {
        @Content(mediaType = "application/json")})})
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:54383")
    public Conductor findConductor(@PathVariable long id) {
        return conductorRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
    }

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public List<Conductor> listaConductores(){
        return conductorRepository.findAll();
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:54383")
    @PostMapping("")
    public void saveConductor(@RequestBody Conductor conductor){
        System.out.println("Received conductor: " + conductor);
        log.info("Conductor: " + conductor.getNombre() + " " + conductor.getApellido());
    }
    
}
```